# CakePHP 2.1 Ajax validation errors

Tags: php, cakephp, cakephp-2.0, cakephp-2.1

I'm trying to get validation errors with Ajax and jQuery working in CakePHP 2.1 for a contact form. On blur of the name field a js function is called:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

$('#name').blur(function(){
    $.post(
        '/Cake_ajax/Contacts/validate_form',
        { field: $(this).attr('id'), value: $(this).val() },
        handleNameValidation
    );
});

function handleNameValidation(error){
    if(error.length > 0){
        if($('#name-notEmpty').length == 0){
            $('#name').after($('<div id="name-notEmpty" class="error-message">' + error + '</div>'));
        }
    }else{
        $('#name-notEmpty').remove();
    }
}
});
```

The javascript calls the validate_form function in my controller:

```
public function validate_form(){
        if($this->RequestHandler->isAjax()){
            $this->request->data['Contact'][$this->request->params['form']['field']] = $this->request->params['form']['value'];
            $this->Contact->set($this->request->data);
            if($this->Contact->validates()){
                $this->autorender = FALSE; // don't render a view
            }else{
                $error = $this->validateErrors($this->Contact);
                $this->set('error', $error[$this->request->params['form']['field']]);
            }
        }
    }
```

In my view I'm getting a couple of errors when the error is called:

```
Undefined index: form [APP\Controller\ContactsController.php
Undefined index: form [APP\Controller\ContactsController.php
```

I'm at my wits end, and I'm fairly new to CakePHP. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your controller you should have something like below. Cake 2.0 replaces many features in RequestHandlerComponent and Controller. It also replaces $this->params array in all places and the old $this->data to $this->request->data, something like that. You can visit the [migration guide](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/appendices/2-0-migration-guide.html#cakerequest).

```
    public function validate_form(){
        if($this->RequestHandler->isAjax()){
           $this->request->data['Contact'][$this->request['form']['field']] = $this->request['form']['value'];
           $this->Contact->set($this->request->data);
           if($this->Contact->validates()){
              $this->autorender = FALSE; // don't render a view
           }else{
             $error = $this->validateErrors($this->Contact);
             // didn't validate logic
             $this->set('error',$this->Contact->validationErrors[$this->request['data']['field']][0]);
          }
       }
    }
```

Comment: Also you can `pr($this->request);` or `pr($this);`

Comment: //didn't validate logic                                          `$this->set('error',$error[$this->request['data']['field']][0]);`

Comment: I changed the 'form' to 'data', and it worked :D thanks heaps.

Answer (score 2):

Try `$this->request->params['field']` instead of `$this->request->params['form']['field']`.

Or right after you check to `isAjax()`, try doing a var_dump on `$this->request->params`.  From the error you are getting, the form index does not exist in `$this->request->params`.

Comment: First bit didn't help I'm afraid. I did a var_dump of 

    $this->request->data

And it returned:

    array(2) { ["field"]=> string(4) "name" ["value"]=> string(0) "" }

Comment: Yeah - take a look at the docs: http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/controllers/request-response.html - you're making the request from an ajax post and not the form submit, so those fields wont be inside a form array.  Hope that helps

Comment: Removed ['form'], now I get: "Undefined index: field" and "Undefined index: field"

Answer (score 0):

If you want to simulate a POST like done when using a standard form and the Cake FormHelper, you could also simply name the posted parameters the same way the FormHelper names the input fields.

```
$j.post(
    '/Cake_ajax/Contacts/validate_form',
    { "data[Contact][" + $(this).attr('id') + "]": $(this).val() },
    handleNameValidation
);
```

This would automatically populate `$this->request->data['Contact']['name']` and you could just comment this line:

```
//$this->request->data['Contact'][$this->request->params['form']['field']] = $this->request->params['form']['value'];
```